# How to get the value of a next iteration of a map in a for each loop of a jstl?

Tags: jstl

I have a LinkedHashMap in my Controller and populate it as follows:

```
    Map<String,String> productCodeURLs  = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

    Iterator<ProductData> it= searchPageData.getResults().iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()) 
    {
        ProductData product=it.next();
        productCodeURLs.put(product.getCode(), product.getUrl());
    }
```

Then in my JSTL, I need to display the value of the next/upcoming iteration.  What's the proper syntax to read the next values?

```
    <c:forEach items="${productMapUrls}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <c:if test="${product.url eq item.value}">
    <c:url var="nextUrl" value="${productMapUrls[loop.index+1].value}"/>

    <a href="${nextUrl}" class="smt-tool"> <span class="icon icon-arrow-next-sm"></span> </a>
    </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
```

But I am unable to get the value of the map in next iteration by using ${productMapUrls[loop.index+1].value}. Please help.

Comment: That should be done by the controller, in Java. Not by the view.

Comment: @JBNizet How to get the value of the map in next iteration by using ${productMapUrls[loop.index+1].value}? Have you any suggestion for getting that?

Comment: I have one, written in my previous comment: do that in the controller, in Java. Not in the view.